# Grains for Mashing and Grains for Steeping

Tags: ingredients, mash, techniques

Does anyone have a list they care to post that lists the "must mash" and "steepable" grains?
Might be nice content for the site overall.

Comment: Want to make this a wiki?

Comment: I don't know if the format of BA lends itself to this kind of wiki. Voting to close the question.

Comment: There aren't enough users yet to actually close a question via votes.. So brewchez would have to do it himself

Comment: I was simply thinking about content for the site here.  Getting more traffic requires a wide range of content.  I was going to post a litst of mashable and steepable grains here eventually if no one got to it.  This type of list is something people google for.  But if providing a link to another site (HBT) is how you want to steer traffic away from the site... I'll close the question.  I would think you'd want this type of content on THIS site.  I am just trying to help. Tell me what you want to do...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the controversy before answering. OK, everyone just be cool.  Making this a community wiki would allow the kind of cooperation that would be necessary to get the content, but StackExchange is not really good at displaying that type of content.

Comment: I don't understand why this would need to be a wiki.  I asked just for a list of mashable and steepable malts.  I then raise the point that from an SEO standpoint does the site really benefit to providing an answer that takes traffic away from the site. In this example to homebrewtalk.  I think this is likely a very relavent point to the admins and owners of the site...especially when the question of self-sustaining revenue is still unanswered.  I am not trying to be a dink here.  Flag me if need be.

Comment: @brewchez @PJ @Dean: Contact me at Fog Creek. You have a friend on the inside. Delete this comment once you've read this.

Comment: I like the idea of getting relevant content on BA. My point is that, like Rich says, StackExchange is not really good at displaying this content. It will end up being a single answer that doesn't utilize the community voting power of the site. A example of this poor use is the "Bottle Labels" post. A good wiki post is the one on "Improving Your Brewing".

Comment: I like the idea of getting relevant content on BA. My point is that, like Rich says, StackExchange is not really good at displaying this content. It will end up being a single answer that doesn't utilize the community voting power of the site. A example of this poor use is the "Bottle Labels" post. A good wiki post is the one on "Improving Your Brewing". Both posts have great content, but only one benefits from voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Malts_Chart